# WPF bound data not loading to bound controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

## EDIT

I've deviated from the methods illustrated here (which I was unable to get to work).

Binding data worked when [I implemented MVVM as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882675/mvvm-load-model-data-when-the-page-loads)

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

I followed a tutorial (which I've since lost the link to) to create a data binding for my DataGrid.

The process involved creating a data source from my model which allowed me to drag a DataGrid onto my Window.

The DataGrid renders empty on the window when I run it and I know for a fact there is data that needs to go into it.

Here's the code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="campaignViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Models:Campaign}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="campaignDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="clientColumn" Binding="{Binding Client}" Header="Client" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dateSentColumn" Header="Date Sent" Width="SizeToHeader">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateSent, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="#" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailAddressColumn" Binding="{Binding EmailAddress}" Header="Email Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

According to the tutorial I built this from, there's nothing more that I need to do to make this work. So what have I missed?

How should I proceed?

Comment: What is your `DataContext`? The `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` only points to `Binding`. I assume your `DataContext` is a `Collection` type?

Comment: That would seem to make sense considering how it created the `CollectionViewSource` in the page resources although if thats the case I don't see why it wouldn't set that ViewSource as the binding source for the DataGrid

Comment: @Ortund Are you setting `DataContext` to anything in code behind or elsewhere in XAML? `ItemsSource="{StaticResource campaignViewSource}"` is the obvious way to use that CollectionViewSource in the grid. If your tutorial suggested `DataContext = this;`, it was written by somebody with a limited understanding of WPF. That seems to be common with tutorials.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm doing nothing else in the code behind (which is probably the problem) but even if I bind DataContext to my collection on the backend, I can't do it the way you suggested: `An object of the type "System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Collections.IEnumerable".`

Comment: @Ortund Whatever "bind datacontext to my collection on the backend" means, don't do that. I steered you slightly wrong: See mm8's answer for the correct way to do what I was struggling to suggest. You need to make it the `Source` of a `Binding`. If it's not working right he'll fix it, you're in good hands now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `ItemsSource` property to your `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="campaignDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource campaignViewSource}}" Grid.Row="1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
```

You also need to set the `Source` property of the `CollectionViewSource` to some source collection:

```
var cvs = this.Resources["campaignViewSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
cvs.Source = new List<YourDataObject> { new YourDataObject(), new YourDataObject() };
```

The drag-and-drop approach is really no good way of either doing or learning something. You should learn XAML and MVVM if you want to become a successful WPF developer.

Comment: An object of the type "System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Collections.IEnumerable".

Comment: Did you really copy my sample markup? You should set the *Source* of the Binding to the CollectionViewSource.

Comment: sorry, no, I just looked at it and got it wrong. It now works, but the DataGrid is still empty

Comment: @Ortund what *mm8* wrote is right, maybe the problem is that the CollectionViewSource is *really* empty, because d:DesignSource applies only at design time and not at runtime..

Comment: You also need to set the Source property of the CollectionViewSource.